# How to change location header when redirect issued by proxied server in nginx

Tags: java, angularjs, nginx, jetty

I have java application running on jetty server where back-end is java rest web service and front end is done with angular js. when my JSESSIONID cookie expires nginx responds with 302 redirect for rest api call. for example http://www.example.com/rest/myapi will return with 302 and location header set to http://www.example.com/. in this case browser will do internal redirect to my home page. Is there any way that i can rewrite location header to 
**www.example.com/rest/myapi**
 so that i get correct api called from browser while performing internal redirect with 302. Here is my nginx configuration for my rest api.

```
# Reverse proxy to the java API.
location ~ ^/rest|redeem|gym|registrant|review|gymview|resources {       
    proxy_pass_header Server;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://api;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_connect_timeout 60;
    proxy_read_timeout 180;
}
```

How do i rewrite location header to call same api again because its calling my home page and getting HTML response instead of JSON and that is breaking my page.
Thank You in advance!!

Comment: Why you use `proxy_redirect off;`?

Comment: Hi @Alexey Ten thanks for reply. actually i am new to nginx and this configuration was done by previous developer. actually i found by googling that we can change Location header by using proxy_redirect but i am not exactly sure how to use it.

Comment: @ Alexey Ten you can see full server configuration in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33429486/nginx-with-backend-jetty-returns-302-for-api-call-whith-wrong-redirect-location

Answer (score 0):

1) you can solve the redirect issue in your Java application so instead of redirecting users to homepage and having an HTML page displayed, you could return some JSON with 401 (unauthorized) response code.

2) Of course you can also use `proxy_redirect` to get them anywhere else than the homepage.
E.g.

```
   proxy_redirect   ~https://$host/       https://$host/rest/myapi;
```

But be smart about it - if the request comes from this particular URL, you'll enter a redirect loop.